# Replacing values using .csv file

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm building a schedule board for our university. I'm already done with the uploading .csv file and it also showing all the data. My problem is, is there any way I can replace the whole data that I've uploaded before in uploading a new .csv file? I mean to delete/replace the old data..

This is my PHP code to upload csv file.

```
<?php
 $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die (mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db("testing",$conn);

 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
    $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    if($file == "")
    {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('No File Selected!');
        </script>
        <?php
    }   

    else
    {
    $handle = fopen($file,"r");

    while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) !==false)
    {
        $subj_desc = $fileop[0];
        $subj_code = $fileop[1];
        $units = $fileop[2];
        $day = $fileop[3];
        $start_time = $fileop[4];
        $end_time = $fileop[5];
        $soc = $fileop[6];
        $eoc = $fileop[7];
        $max = $fileop[8];
        $room = $fileop[9];
        $term = $fileop[10];
        $lecturer = $fileop[11];

        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tbl_schedule_board` (`subj_desc`,`subj_code`,`units`,`day`,`start_time`,`end_time`,`soc`,`eoc`,`max`,`room`, `term`, `lecturer`)
        VALUES (
                '" . mysql_real_escape_string($subj_desc) . "',
                '" . mysql_real_escape_string($subj_code) . "',
                '" . mysql_real_escape_string($units) . "',
                '" . mysql_real_escape_string($day) . "',
                '" . mysql_real_escape_string($start_time) . "',
                '" . mysql_real_escape_string($end_time) . "',
                '" . mysql_real_escape_string($soc) . "',
                '" . mysql_real_escape_string($eoc) . "',
                '" . mysql_real_escape_string($max) . "',
                '" . mysql_real_escape_string($room) . "',
                '" . mysql_real_escape_string($term) . "',
                '" . mysql_real_escape_string($lecturer) . "')");
    }
     if($sql)
     {
        echo '<script> alert("Data Successfully Uploaded."); </script>';
     }
    }
}
```

?>

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean replace existing records with the new data? Option one: delete records by the username (that's your unique ID?) before inserting the new record, or option two: use a [`REPLACE INTO`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) statement instead of `INSERT`

Comment: I'll try the second option, and I'll get back to you :) Thanks scrowler

Comment: I'm not sure where your data is coming from, but I would probably read up on SQL injection if I were you.

Comment: Hello Scrowler, I can't have a unique/primary key on my table because, I have Same subjects, subject code but different on Time Schedule.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete **all** old data from table use [TRUNCATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/truncate-table.html) command:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `users_sched`;
```

Comment: Hello baf, I want to replace all the data on the database if I uploaded a new csv file.

Comment: So you could `TRUNCATE` the table before inserting new data

Comment: So instead of using INSERT INTO, I'll use TRUNCATE?

Comment: You use `TRUNCATE` before `INSERT`. It will empty your table.

Comment: What happens if the CSV only contains 3 users this time, you truncate your table and lose the other 10 thousand students data?

Comment: What's the best way to replace a single row in uploading a csv file?

Comment: If you want to replace only some rows go for @scrowler suggestion and use `REPLACE`, but you need a unique or primary key.

Comment: Hi @baf , I already put `code`$sql2 = mysql_query("TRUNCATE `tbl_schedule_board`"); `code` before my INSERT INTO code, but it only truncates and when I upload a new csv file, it uploads but it doesn't show on the database.